# Causing an Angular form to POST

Tags: forms, angularjs

When a form is valid, I want it to POST the value to a web site.

I get the alert to fire nicely when the form is **not valid**, but I can't set the action and cause the form to submit when the form **is valid**.

So, the result should be that the form posts and the browser goes to the next page like a traditional html form.

```
 <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm)" novalidate>
 ......

 validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

// function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
  $scope.submitForm = function(form) {

   if(form.$invalid){
       alert("form invalid");
   }
   else
   {
      form.action="http://microsoft.com";
      form.submit();
   }

 };


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't works that way. Angular mostly expects a RESTful web service to answer its calls. Yes, you can get it working with action somehow. However, for redirecting you would have to make use of `$location` web service. Through `$location` you can redirect your page to next page.

```
$scope.submitForm=function(form){
if(form.$invalid){
       alert("form invalid");
}
else
{
      $http.post(url:'yourURL', yourData));
      $location.path='newURL';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation on ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit):

Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.

Otherwise, I think you can pass `$event` to the function and trigger `$event.srcElement.submit()`. The object you're passing to the function isn't the form element itself, which is why it won't submit. If you want, you can pass both by doing `ng-submit="submitForm($event, userForm)"`. Hope that helps!